# How to enable a Roslyn analyzer or refactoring that was automatically disabled due to crashes?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

How to enable a Roslyn analyzer or refactoring that was previously automatically disabled due to crashes?

Comment: Is it disabled if you look at the specific rule under _References_ > _Analyzers_ > _Open Active Ruleset_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an analyzer crashes, we don't disable it. We catch and log the exception and let it continue because it could have just not have understood some ill formed tree.

When a code fixer or code refactoring crashes, we disable the fixer but pop up an info bar on top of the editor that lets you reenable the fixer. If you dismiss that fixer however, there's no way to enable it again for that session (you'd have to restart VS to get it back).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had assumed it's permanently disabled - not just for the current session.